# SWT: paint on parts of a given composite control like Table-headers or the button of a Combo

Tags: controls, swt, paint

The title is pretty self-explanatory, i'm currently adding `PaintListener`s to all the children, grand-children and so on, of the control i'd like to paint on. I have graphical errors with `Table`s and `Combo`s at the moment, the PaintListener apparently doesn't apply to the header or the button in the combo.

How can i do this?

This is the code i use to add the listeners:

```
List<Control> controls = Lists.newArrayList();
controls.add(composite);

while (! controls.isEmpty()) {

    Control c = controls.remove(0); 
    if (c instanceof Composite) {
        controls.addAll(Arrays.asList(((Composite) c).getChildren()));
    }

    c.addPaintListener(new ControlPaintListener());
}
```

Comment: Are you wrapping the `Combo` in another `Composite` and hooking a `PaintListener` on *it*?  Or are you hooking a `PaintListener` on the `Combo`?  Add some example code maybe?

Comment: It's a rather deep-hierarchy, i start from a top-composite and add to all controls i can find within. One of these is a combo, one is a table. Painting works everywhere except on the dropdown-button of the Combo and the Table-Headers.